# Creating project using platformio VScode extension taking too much time and stucks in project wizard window

Tags: ide, esp32, platformio

I have dowloaded Platformio extension in VS code for development. I have selected the following board "ESP32 devkit v1" in IDE. When I create a project using platformio, it stuck in the project wizard window for very long time. Kindly suggest some solution for this issue?

I am trying to make a new project but in project wizard window it stuck for a very long period of time.